# which version of mongodb should I install for windows6?

Tags: mongodb

When I go to https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community I don't see a version specific to windows7 64bit to install?which version should I install for windows6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this seems not clear. But you need to use the Windows Server 2008 R2 64-Bit Installer, with or without SSL support.

The others are a 32-Bit version and a legay 64-Bit version of mongodb, that does not make use of some windows features.

So [this](https://www.mongodb.com/dr/fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.2.7-signed.msi/download) (with SSL) or [this](https://www.mongodb.com/dr/fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-3.2.7-signed.msi/download) (without SSL).

Heres a [reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) to the Installation instructions of MongoDB.

> MongoDB for Windows 64-bit runs only on Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows 7 64-bit, and newer versions of Windows. This build takes advantage of recent enhancements to the Windows Platform and cannot operate on older versions of Windows.
>
> MongoDB for Windows 64-bit Legacy runs on Windows Vista, and Windows Server 2008 and does not include recent performance enhancements.

Comment: jehof - thanks,which of `with SSH` and `without SSH` is preferred,which one do folks normally install

Comment: @PythonProg I not sure what with/without SSH referes too (this is since version 3.0), but I would use the `with SSH` build. Its the preferred one on the download page.